# неразрешенный внешний символ rwim3dend и другие

Tags: c++, c

я создаю ASI плагин для игры GTA SA, и у меня есть 11 ошибок, решение которых я не могу выяснить. Будьте любезны, помогите пожалуйста...

Rubbish.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Rubbish.h"

#include "Game.h"
#include "TxdStore.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "World.h"
#include "Weather.h"
#include "Timer.h"
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include "debugmenu_public.h"



        int CRubbish::RubbishVisibility;
        bool CRubbish::bRubbishInvisible;
        COneSheet CRubbish::aSheets[CRubbish::NUMSHEETS];
        COneSheet CRubbish::StartEmptyList, CRubbish::EndEmptyList;
        COneSheet CRubbish::StartStaticsList, CRubbish::EndStaticsList;
        COneSheet CRubbish::StartMoversList, CRubbish::EndMoversList;
        RwTexture* CRubbish::gpRubbishTexture[4];

        void
            COneSheet::AddToList(COneSheet * list)
        {
            this->prev = list;
            this->next = list->next;
            list->next = this;
            this->next->prev = this;
        }

        void
            COneSheet::RemoveFromList(void)
        {
            this->next->prev = this->prev;
            this->prev->next = this->next;
        }

        void
            CRubbish::Init(void)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < NUMSHEETS; i++) {
                aSheets[i].type = 0;
                if (i == 0)
                    aSheets[i].prev = &StartEmptyList;
                else
                    aSheets[i].prev = &aSheets[i - 1];
                if (i + 1 >= NUMSHEETS)
                    aSheets[i].next = &EndEmptyList;
                else
                    aSheets[i].next = &aSheets[i + 1];
            }

            StartEmptyList.next = &aSheets[0];
            StartEmptyList.prev = NULL;
            EndEmptyList.next = NULL;
            EndEmptyList.prev = &aSheets[NUMSHEETS - 1];

            StartStaticsList.next = &EndStaticsList;
            StartStaticsList.prev = NULL;
            EndStaticsList.next = NULL;
            CRubbish::EndStaticsList.prev = &CRubbish::StartStaticsList;

            CRubbish::StartMoversList.next = &CRubbish::EndMoversList;
            CRubbish::StartMoversList.prev = NULL;
            CRubbish::EndMoversList.next = NULL;
            CRubbish::EndMoversList.prev = &CRubbish::StartMoversList;
            CTxdStore::PushCurrentTxd();
            CTxdStore::SetCurrentTxd(CTxdStore::FindTxdSlot("rubbish"));
            gpRubbishTexture[0] = RwTextureRead("gameleaf01_64", NULL);
            gpRubbishTexture[1] = RwTextureRead("gameleaf02_64", NULL);
            gpRubbishTexture[2] = RwTextureRead("newspaper01_64", NULL);
            gpRubbishTexture[3] = RwTextureRead("newspaper02_64", NULL);
            CTxdStore::PopCurrentTxd();
            CRubbish::RubbishVisibility = 255;
            CRubbish::bRubbishInvisible = false;
        }

        void
            CRubbish::StirUp(CVehicle * vehicle)
        {
            if ((CTimer::m_FrameCounter ^ vehicle->RandomSeed) & 3)
                return;

            CVector campos = TheCamera.GetCoords();
            CVector vehpos = vehicle->GetCoords();
            if (abs(campos.x - vehpos.x) > 20.0f ||
                abs(campos.y - vehpos.y) > 20.0f)
                return;

            CVector speedvec = vehicle->GetLinearVelocity();
            if (abs(speedvec.x) <= 0.05f && abs(speedvec.y) <= 0.05f)
                return;

            float speed = CVector(speedvec.x, speedvec.y, 0.0f).Magnitude();
            if (speed <= 0.05f)
                return;

            CVector* up = vehicle->GetMatrix()->GetUp();
            CVector* right = vehicle->GetMatrix()->GetRight();
            float speed_dot_up = speedvec.x * up->x + speedvec.y * up->y;

            CColModel* col = CModelInfo::GetModelInfo(vehicle->GetModelIndex())->GetColModel();
            float length = col->boundingBox.vecMax.y;
            float width = col->boundingBox.vecMax.x;

            COneSheet* sheet, * next;
            for (sheet = StartStaticsList.next; sheet != &EndStaticsList; sheet = next) {
                next = sheet->next;
                float dx = sheet->vec1.x - vehpos.x;
                float dy = sheet->vec1.y - vehpos.y;
                float dist_dot_up = dx * up->x + dy * up->y;
                float dist_dot_right = abs(dx * right->x + dy * right->y);

                // this is all weird
                if (speed_dot_up > 0.0f && dist_dot_up < -0.5f * length && dist_dot_up > -1.5f * length ||
                    speed_dot_up <= 0.0f && dist_dot_up > 0.5f * length && dist_dot_up < 1.5f * length) {
                    float s = dist_dot_right >= width ? 0.5f * speed : speed;
                    if (dist_dot_right < 1.5f * width && s > 0.05f) {
                        sheet->type = 2;
                        sheet->movementType = s <= 0.15f ? 1 : 2;
                        sheet->duration = 2000;
                        float l = sqrt(speedvec.x * speedvec.x + speedvec.y * speedvec.y);
                        sheet->moveOffsetX = speedvec.x / l * speed * 25.0f;
                        sheet->moveOffsetY = speedvec.y / l * speed * 25.0f;
                        sheet->moveOffsetZ = speed * 3.0f;
                        sheet->startTime = CTimer::m_snTimeInMilliseconds;
                        sheet->moveTargetZ = CWorld::FindGroundZFor3DCoord(
                            sheet->vec1.x + sheet->moveOffsetX,
                            sheet->vec1.y + sheet->moveOffsetY,
                            sheet->vec1.z + 3.0f, NULL, NULL) + 0.1f;
                        sheet->RemoveFromList();
                        sheet->AddToList(&StartMoversList);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static uint8 rand8(void) { return rand(); }

        WRAPPER int CCullZones__FindAttributesForCoors(float x, float y, float z) { EAXJMP(0x72D970); }

        static float
            FindGroundForRubbish(float x, float y, float z, bool* success)
        {
            float groundz = CWorld::FindGroundZFor3DCoord(x, y, z, success, NULL);
            return groundz;

            // get the water to work right :/
            //  if(CWaterLevel::GetWaterLevel(x, y, z, &waterz, false, NULL))
            //      ;
        }

        void
            CRubbish::Update(void)
        {
            COneSheet* sheet;

            if (bRubbishInvisible) {
                RubbishVisibility -= 5;
                if (RubbishVisibility < 0)
                    RubbishVisibility = 0;
            }
            else {
                RubbishVisibility += 5;
                if (RubbishVisibility > 255)
                    RubbishVisibility = 255;
            }

            CVector campos = TheCamera.GetCoords();

            // Generate new sheets
            sheet = StartEmptyList.next;
            if (sheet != &EndEmptyList) {
                float radius = rand8() / 255.0f + 23.0f;
                float angle;
                uint8 r = rand8();
                if (r & 1)
                    angle = rand8() / 255.0f * M_PI * 2.0f;
                else
                    angle = (r - 128) / 160.0f + TheCamera.Orientation;
                sheet->vec1.x = sin(angle) * radius + campos.x;
                sheet->vec1.y = cos(angle) * radius + campos.y;
                bool foundGround;
                sheet->vec1.z = FindGroundForRubbish(sheet->vec1.x, sheet->vec1.y, campos.z, &foundGround) + 0.1f;
                if (foundGround) {
                    sheet->angle = rand8() / 255.0f * M_PI * 2.0f;
                    sheet->type = 1;
                    if (CCullZones__FindAttributesForCoors(sheet->vec1.x, sheet->vec1.y, sheet->vec1.z) & 8)
                        sheet->zoneVisible1 = 0;
                    else
                        sheet->zoneVisible1 = 1;
                    sheet->RemoveFromList();
                    sheet->AddToList(&StartStaticsList);
                }
            }

            static float movement[3][34] = {
                { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },

            { 0, 0.05, 0.12, 0.25, 0.42, 0.57, 0.68, 0.8, 0.86, 0.9, 0.93, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1, // XY movemnt
            0.15, 0.35, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 0.95, 0.8, 0.6, 0.45, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0 },   // Z movement

            { 0, 0.05, 0.12, 0.25, 0.42, 0.57, 0.68, 0.8, 0.95, 1.1, 1.15, 1.18, 1.15, 1.1, 1.05, 1.03, 1,
            0.15, 0.35, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.25, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 0.95, 0.8, 0.6, 0.45, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0 }
            };
            // Update Movers
            COneSheet* next;
            for (sheet = StartMoversList.next; sheet != &EndMoversList; sheet = next) {
                next = sheet->next;
                int t = CTimer::m_snTimeInMilliseconds - sheet->startTime;
                if (t < sheet->duration) {
                    int step = 16 * t / sheet->duration;    // 16 steps
                    float stepInterp = (t - sheet->duration / 16.0f * step) / (sheet->duration / 16.0f);    // interpolation along step
                    float interp = (float)t / sheet->duration;  // interpolation along total animation
                    float moveMult = stepInterp * movement[sheet->movementType][step + 1] +
                        (1.0f - stepInterp) * movement[sheet->movementType][step];
                    float moveMultZ = stepInterp * movement[sheet->movementType][step + 1 + 17] +
                        (1.0f - stepInterp) * movement[sheet->movementType][step + 17];

                    sheet->vec2.x = sheet->vec1.x + sheet->moveOffsetX * moveMult;
                    sheet->vec2.y = sheet->vec1.y + sheet->moveOffsetY * moveMult;
                    sheet->vec2.z = interp * sheet->moveTargetZ + (1.0f - interp) * sheet->vec1.z +
                        sheet->moveOffsetZ * moveMultZ;
                    sheet->angle += CTimer::ms_fTimeStep / 25.0f;
                    if (sheet->angle > 2 * M_PI)
                        sheet->angle -= 2 * M_PI;
                }
                else {
                    // Move done, make static again
                    sheet->vec1.x += sheet->moveOffsetX;
                    sheet->vec1.y += sheet->moveOffsetY;
                    sheet->vec1.z = sheet->moveTargetZ;
                    sheet->type = 1;
                    sheet->zoneVisible1 = sheet->zoneVisible2;
                    sheet->RemoveFromList();
                    sheet->AddToList(&StartStaticsList);
                }
            }

            int freq;
            if (CWeather::Wind < 0.1f)
                freq = 0x1F;
            else if (CWeather::Wind < 0.4f)
                freq = 7;
            else if (CWeather::Wind < 0.7f)
                freq = 1;
            else
                freq = 0;

            // Turn Statics into Movers
            if ((CTimer::m_FrameCounter & freq) == 0) {
                int i = rand() & (NUMSHEETS - 1);
                sheet = &aSheets[i];
                if (sheet->type == 1) {
                    sheet->startTime = CTimer::m_snTimeInMilliseconds;
                    sheet->duration = CWeather::Wind * 1500.0f + 1000.0f;
                    sheet->moveOffsetZ = 0.2f;
                    sheet->moveOffsetX = CWeather::Wind * 3.0f;
                    sheet->moveOffsetY = CWeather::Wind * 3.0f;
                    bool foundGround;
                    sheet->moveTargetZ = FindGroundForRubbish(sheet->vec1.x + sheet->moveOffsetX, sheet->vec1.y + sheet->moveOffsetY, sheet->vec1.z, &foundGround) + 0.1f;
                    if (CCullZones__FindAttributesForCoors(sheet->vec1.x + sheet->moveOffsetX, sheet->vec1.y + sheet->moveOffsetY, sheet->moveTargetZ) & 8)
                        sheet->zoneVisible2 = 0;
                    else
                        sheet->zoneVisible2 = 1;
                    if (foundGround) {
                        sheet->type = 2;
                        sheet->movementType = 1;
                        sheet->RemoveFromList();
                        sheet->AddToList(&StartMoversList);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Remove sheets that are too far away
            // Actually only two per frame
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < NUMSHEETS; i++) {
                if (aSheets[i].type != 1)
                    continue;
                if (aSheets[i].vec1.DistanceXY(campos) > 24.0f) {
                    aSheets[i].type = 0;
                    aSheets[i].RemoveFromList();
                    aSheets[i].AddToList(&StartEmptyList);
                }
            }
        }

        static int TempBufferIndicesStored;
        static int TempBufferVerticesStored;
        static RwIm3DVertex TempVertexBuffer[512];
        static RwImVertexIndex TempBufferRenderIndexList[1024];

        void
            CRubbish::Render(void)
        {
            if (RubbishVisibility == 0 || CGame::currArea > 0)
                return;

            int alphafunc;
            RwRenderStateGet(rwRENDERSTATEALPHATESTFUNCTION, &alphafunc);
            RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATEALPHATESTFUNCTION, (void*)rwALPHATESTFUNCTIONALWAYS);

            RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATEZWRITEENABLE, 0);
            RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATEVERTEXALPHAENABLE, (void*)TRUE);
            RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATEFOGENABLE, (void*)TRUE);

            int textype;
            for (textype = 0; textype < 4; textype++) {
                if (textype < 3)
                    RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATETEXTURERASTER, RwTextureGetRaster(gpRubbishTexture[textype]));
                TempBufferIndicesStored = 0;
                TempBufferVerticesStored = 0;

                for (COneSheet* sheet = &aSheets[textype * (NUMSHEETS / 4)];
                    sheet < &aSheets[(textype + 1) * (NUMSHEETS / 4)];
                    sheet++) {
                    if (sheet->type == 0)
                        continue;

                    int alpha = 100;
                    CVector pos;
                    if (sheet->type == 1) {
                        pos = sheet->vec1;
                        if (!sheet->zoneVisible1)
                            alpha = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        pos = sheet->vec2;
                        if (!sheet->zoneVisible1 || !sheet->zoneVisible2) {
                            float t = (float)(CTimer::m_snTimeInMilliseconds - sheet->startTime) / sheet->duration;
                            float f1 = sheet->zoneVisible1 ? 1.0f - t : 0.0f;
                            float f2 = sheet->zoneVisible2 ? t : 0.0f;
                            alpha = 100 * (f1 + f2);
                        }
                    }

                    float dist = pos.DistanceXY(TheCamera.GetCoords());
                    if (dist > 23.0f)
                        continue;
                    if (dist > 20.0f)
                        alpha -= alpha * (dist - 20.0f) / (23.0f - 20.0f);

                    float vx1, vx2;
                    float vy1, vy2;
                    static float sizes[4] = { 0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.3 }; // all square in VCS

                    vx1 = sin(sheet->angle) * sizes[textype];
                    vy1 = cos(sheet->angle) * sizes[textype];
                    vx2 = cos(sheet->angle) * sizes[textype];
                    vy2 = -sin(sheet->angle) * sizes[textype];

                    alpha = RubbishVisibility * alpha / 255;

                    int i = TempBufferVerticesStored;
                    RwIm3DVertexSetPos(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 0], pos.x + vx1 + vx2, pos.y + vy1 + vy2, pos.z);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetPos(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 1], pos.x + vx1 - vx2, pos.y + vy1 - vy2, pos.z);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetPos(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 2], pos.x - vx1 + vx2, pos.y - vy1 + vy2, pos.z);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetPos(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 3], pos.x - vx1 - vx2, pos.y - vy1 - vy2, pos.z);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetRGBA(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 0], 255, 255, 255, alpha);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetRGBA(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 1], 255, 255, 255, alpha);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetRGBA(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 2], 255, 255, 255, alpha);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetRGBA(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 3], 255, 255, 255, alpha);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetU(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 0], 0.0f);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetV(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 0], 0.0f);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetU(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 1], 1.0f);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetV(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 1], 0.0f);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetU(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 2], 0.0f);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetV(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 2], 1.0f);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetU(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 3], 1.0f);
                    RwIm3DVertexSetV(&TempVertexBuffer[i + 3], 1.0f);

                    TempBufferRenderIndexList[TempBufferIndicesStored++] = TempBufferVerticesStored + 0;
                    TempBufferRenderIndexList[TempBufferIndicesStored++] = TempBufferVerticesStored + 1;
                    TempBufferRenderIndexList[TempBufferIndicesStored++] = TempBufferVerticesStored + 2;
                    TempBufferRenderIndexList[TempBufferIndicesStored++] = TempBufferVerticesStored + 1;
                    TempBufferRenderIndexList[TempBufferIndicesStored++] = TempBufferVerticesStored + 3;
                    TempBufferRenderIndexList[TempBufferIndicesStored++] = TempBufferVerticesStored + 2;
                    TempBufferVerticesStored += 4;
                }
 
                if (TempBufferIndicesStored) {
                    if (RwIm3DTransform(TempVertexBuffer, TempBufferVerticesStored, NULL, rwIM3D_VERTEXUV)) {
                        RwIm3DRenderIndexedPrimitive(rwPRIMTYPETRILIST, TempBufferRenderIndexList, TempBufferIndicesStored);
                        RwIm3DEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATEFOGENABLE, 0);
            RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATEZWRITEENABLE, 0);
            RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATEVERTEXALPHAENABLE, (void*)TRUE);

            RwRenderStateSet(rwRENDERSTATEALPHATESTFUNCTION, (void*)alphafunc);
        }

        void
            CRubbish::SetVisibility(bool v)
        {
            bRubbishInvisible = !v;
        }

        static StaticPatcher Patcher([]() {
            Memory::InjectHook(0x7204C0, CRubbish::SetVisibility, PATCH_JUMP);
            if (DebugMenuLoad()) {
                DebugMenuAddVarBool8("Rendering", "Rubbish invisible", (int8*)&CRubbish::bRubbishInvisible, NULL);
            }
            });
```

rubbish.h

```
#ifndef __RUBBISH
#define __RUBBISH

struct COneSheet
{
    CVector vec1;
    CVector vec2;
    float moveTargetZ;
    int8 type;
    int8 movementType;
    int32 startTime;
    int32 duration;
    float moveOffsetZ;
    float moveOffsetX;
    float moveOffsetY;
    float angle;
    int8 zoneVisible1;
    int8 zoneVisible2;
    int8 unk72;
    int8 unk73;
    COneSheet *next;
    COneSheet *prev;

    void AddToList(COneSheet *list);
    void RemoveFromList(void);
};

class CVehicle;

class CRubbish
{
public:
    // MUST be a power of 2
    enum { NUMSHEETS = 32 };

    static int RubbishVisibility;
    static bool bRubbishInvisible;
    static COneSheet aSheets[NUMSHEETS];
    static COneSheet StartEmptyList, EndEmptyList;
    static COneSheet StartStaticsList, EndStaticsList;
    static COneSheet StartMoversList, EndMoversList;
    static RwTexture *gpRubbishTexture[4];

    static void Init(void);
    static void Update(void);
    static void StirUp(CVehicle *vehicle);
    static void Render(void);
    static void SetVisibility(bool v);
};

#endif
```

Ошибки:

```
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ _RwIm3DEnd.
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ _RwTextureRead.
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ _RwIm3DRenderIndexedPrimitive.
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ _RwEngineInstance.
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall StaticPatcher::StaticPatcher(void (__cdecl*)(void))" (??0StaticPatcher@@QAE@P6AXXZ@Z).
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static class CBaseModelInfo * * CModelInfo::ms_modelInfoPtrs" (?ms_modelInfoPtrs@CModelInfo@@2QAPAVCBaseModelInfo@@A).
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ _RwIm3DTransform.
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static int & CTimer::m_snTimeInMilliseconds" (?m_snTimeInMilliseconds@CTimer@@2AAHA).
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static double __cdecl CWorld::FindGroundZFor3DCoord(float,float,float,bool *,class CEntity * *)" (?FindGroundZFor3DCoord@CWorld@@SANMMMPA_NPAPAVCEntity@@@Z).
Rubbish.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ _gDebugMenuAPI.
O:\GTA San Andreas\scripts\vcrubbish.SA.asi : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 10
```

Comment: В ошибках явно говорится про неразрешенный внешний символ. Ну, например, `_RwIm3DEnd` — это библиотека DirectX, включите заголовочный файл `d3d9.h`. Если SA — это San Andreas, кажется 9-ая версия dx актуальна была на тот момент.

Comment: это не библиотека directx, это штука renderware, #include d3d9.h также не помогла